# Autocorrelation of residuals in my VAR model

Tags: forecasting, residuals, autocorrelation, vector-autoregression

I am running a VAR model to predict the flow of consumer loans (dependent variable). I have three independent variables (consumption of durables goods, employment rate and households GFCF). Each variable has 76 quarterly observations. My four series are stationary in difference. Results are confirmed by ADF and PP test. I tried to run several VAR with different specifications (add and change in the independent variables, tried different p order, add a dummy variable to capture an outline in 2020 because of the pandemic crisis). Nonetheless, my residuals are still highly autocorrelated. I can't understand why. I do maybe miss something. My residuals are also non-normally distributed (which seems to be not very important for forecasting as I have understood).

If anyone has some suggestions and recommendations, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Could you include a plot of your residuals (all four series)? Perhaps there are some outliers or breaks that cause the measured autocorrelation to be high?